# Spring Boot application generic logging of user activity

Tags: spring

I have a Spring Boot application with various REST endpoints. There is a requirement to log the user activity to the database. The logging should ideally be a seperate module. The user activity logged should include the user name, client IP address, activity name/operation name and the parameters and the values that are being updated. The different REST endpoints have different request body entities. So for e.g. the rest end point for creating a resource will have a different request body to the rest end point for say setting an equipment parameter.

For logging as a seperate module, I can think of 2 approaches:

1. Using a filter
   Created a logging filter and registered it using FilterRegistrationBean, adding the specific urls interested in logging for. I am able to get the request and response details for the requests to the urls. In this case cannot get the operation name that is called though.
2. Using Spring AOP

However since the request body entities are different for different end points, is there a way to generically parse the request body to get the parameters and their values so that in the common logging filter a message can be created of the type "User ${username} performed ${operation name} on parameters ${parameters} with values ${values}"?

Comment: what is the message format that your web service consumes?
if it's JSON, you can use basically any JSON library to get parameters value by key.